# Scala unapply with generic parameter

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, case-class

So I want to make sure that the extractor in the case match will give an alias to it the correct generic type, if possible.

```
trait MyT[A]

case class MyC[A](t: MyT[A])

def foo: MyC[_]

def go[A](t: MyT[A]): Option[MyC[A]] = foo match {
  case m@MyC(`t`) => Some(m.copy(t = t))
  case _ => None
}
```

This works but I would prefer to not do the `m.copy(t = t)`. Basically `m@` will bind to `MyC[Any]`, but I want it to bind to `MyC[A]`. Is this possible, maybe with a custom `unapply`?

Comment: foo actually returns MyC[_] and its not clear how I would change this in my code. I need to rely on foo.

Comment: `m.copy(t = t)` will just call `MyC(t)`, so you could write that instead and don't need `m` here (which may not apply to your real code, of course). Of course, reusing `m` would be better, but this seems to be a strict improvement on `copy` to me.

Comment: It's not. If I ever add fields to `MyC`, I would need to change the case match as well as the result, whereas copy means I only need to change the case match.

Comment: Only if the added fields aren't related to `A`, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to explicitly ascribe the type parameter `A` to the pattern matched `MyC`, and eliminate the warnings by `@unchecked`:

```
trait MyT[A]

case class MyC[A](t: MyT[A])

def foo: MyC[_] = ???

def go[A](t: MyT[A]): Option[MyC[A]] = foo match {
  case m: MyC[A @unchecked] if (m.t == t) => Some(m)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Honestly, imo worse then my useless copy, because the `@unchecked` hurts me.

Comment: @allidoiswin Does it hurt even more than the fact that the compiler attempts to pattern match `m` against a `MyC(\`t\`)` without complaining? Or that the compiler allows invocations of `==` on values which aren't even necessary of same type?

Comment: well for the `==` it uses `.equals` no? I'm not sure what you mean with the first one about `m` vs `MyC(\`t\`)`

Comment: @allidoiswin Yes, `==` uses `equals`. I just don't see any great difference between the above `@unchecked` and something like `def foobar[A](a: A, b: AnyRef): Option[A] = {
  if (a == b) Some(a) else None
}`. When using `==`, it doesn't even require an `@unchecked` annotation for essentially same kind of "unsafe"-ish comparison.

Comment: @allidoiswin In the previous comment, from `a == b` you can conclude that `b` is of type `A` in the `then`-branch of the `if`. Likewise, if `m.t == t`, you can derive that `m.t` must be of type `MyT[A]`, therefore `m` must be of type `MyC[A]`. The compiler doesn't see that, because it doesn't infer anything useful from the fact that `m.t == t`. This is not flow-sensitive typing, unfortunately...

Comment: perhaps, but wouldn't the `==` actually be "safe" in the sense that `equals` can actually take in an `Any`? It's "safe" by api.

edit: yes you can deduce `m.t` it `MyT[A]`, I just want the compiler to deduce that `m` is `MyC[A]`.